# jquery background animation conflict with #anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Im creating a background animation and i'm having issue when for some reason there is a link anchor in the site content. The animation still works but it cuts the site header section and it wont allow you to scroll back to the top of the site.

Not sure I explained this properly but it is much easier to see it working here:

[Example of the animation working ok on the index page](http://www.sitesplat.com/testing/index.php)

[Example of the animation causing the header to be cut off](http://www.sitesplat.com/testing/viewtopic.php?f=2&p=3#p3)

How can i fix this behavior? (I have absolutely no idea)

EDIT. FIXED IT BY ADDING position FIXED. Thx all.

Comment: The issue is with `overflow-hidden` on `#animation-container`. You probably need to move `#wrap` outside of the animation container somehow

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it is due to `container-fluid` class applied to the div having **animation-container** id.

please replace following statement :

`<div id="animation-container" class="container-fluid">`

by

`<div id="animation-container" class="">`

In your `viewtopic.php` page.

Comment: Thx for the help on this. If I delete the container-fluid the animation will not work for all the length on the container box but it will get cut off halfway before the footer.. any other suggestions? I guess it's trickier because I have a boxed space and the animation is outside.

Comment: you just try this url and tell me you are getting cutoff the header? http://www.sitesplat.com/testing/viewtopic.php?f=2&p=3

Comment: not in that one. Only when you click on the actual post number. for example this: http://www.sitesplat.com/testing/viewtopic.php?p=1#p1

Comment: Fixed it. Thx all. I added a position fixed attr.